# C : Function Declaration

Tags: c, function, cs50

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <cs50.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <ctype.h>

 int count_letters(string text[]);
 int main(void)
 {
    string text= get_string("Please enter text: ");
    printf("%i Letter(s)  \n",countl);
 }
 int count_letters(string text[])
 {
    int countl= 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
      if (isalpha(text[i]) != 0)
      {
        countl++;
      }
  }
  return countl;
  }
```

Hello everyone, I consulted my textbook and various educational resources on "How to declare a function in C" and I still can't make it work. In this code I want the function count_letters to return the value "countl" which I can then print on the screen. Please help me to understand how to declare this function correctly.

Comment: I _think_ that `cs50` defines `string` as `char *` or something so replacing `(string text[])` by `(string text)` should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has two main issues.

#### 1.

The parameter `text` of `count_letters` is of wrong type. `string` is an `cs50.h` alias for `char *`. `text` needs to be either of type `string` or `char *` or `char []` which is in the case as a function parameter equivalent to `char *`.

Use either

```
int count_letters (string text)
```

or

```
int count_letters (char* text)
```

or

```
int count_letters (char text[])
```

but not

```
int count_letters (string text[])
```

With `string text[]` `text` would be of type `char **`, which is wrong since you don't want to modify the pointer itself in `count_letters`.

Optionally, You also can make the pointer and/or the pointed object `const` to ensure no misuse or overwrites.

#### 2.

You never call the function `count_letters` in `main`. You need to call it to get its returned value.

```
 int main(void)
 {
    string text = get_string("Please enter text: ");
    printf("%i Letter(s)  \n", count_letters(text));
 }
```

---

Side Notes:

- You should cast the argument to `isalpha()` to `unsigned char` to ensure no [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984) occurs when not passing an appropriate character.
- `n = strlen(text); i < n;` inside of the `for` loop in `count_letters` can be replaced by just the condition `text[i] != '\0'` or even more simpler `text[i]`.
- Since you don't intend to provide a negative return value, you could use a return type of `unsigned int` or `size_t` for `check_letters`. You need to change the format specifier in the `printf()` call in `main` too to either `%u` for `unsigned int` or `%zu` for `size_t`.

---

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <cs50.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <ctype.h>

 unsigned int count_letters (const string text);

 int main (void)
 {
     const string text = get_string("Please enter text: ");
     putchar('\n');         
     printf("%u Letter(s)  \n", count_letters(text));
 }

 unsigned int count_letters (const string text)
 {
     unsigned int countl = 0;
     for (unsigned int i = 0; text[i] ; i++)
     {
         if (isalpha((unsigned char)text[i]))
         {
             countl++;
         } 
     }

     return countl;
 }
```

Execution:

```
./a.out
Please enter text: hello
5 Letter(s)
```

[Online Test](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaXAGylV6ADJ5amAHJ6ARpmJcATKQAOqaYSW1NO/Ubunt50Fla2ug5OnK6y8op0DATMxAR%2BegacxnGYCj5JKQRhNvaOLjLJqekBWRWFxRFRLgCUMqjaxMgcAOQApM4AzJbIOlgA1L0D6tIE%2BKgAdAiT2L0ADACC/UO0I9rjk%2BrI0gCsq4vLa5uDw6OYE1MzxJbA5wMrG1s3e3cHCgCebkwr3emw2Y20tC8wCs6DGlgIYzQEIIYnYBAIjmkEEezzGGIAHgRmpMAEKXS5w%2BhjXTMSxjCAAN1QeHQxLBvQA7GSwWNeWMcaI8ZhCfcACJjYCYFEC4AQfrOAAK7GYsjGqgxxCFhJAE2czmJA256z5vLc2gIyAQKQgYD6x3UtFtBqNJrGbie9Cocr1/WO2jGZilGuxzV5vXttHlpER7XoqKDmIgBKJzopnNF5LBEKhMMpCKRcbRGuk9JlWqJaa5FJN2bw0MwsPhMeRrDFY1WpOrfJomogtfrjapeDbHcN5fDJLw4fFpLh/TJzhJbONJs5LtdfLwVHpeGkbDcVqg/dzlpSzWTE6nx1FzWXG75a67975BYIrHnH8NT9d6YmPIfHIZh8/68sQUodLQzb0O%2BX7soB3StKwIDdMc3SkAY3SrGhqDIeo/LtJ0PyDJwaEEMhWG3qQADWIADMc8yrNwHIAByrByhiGBynCrM43DMUIyHcGhGFYaQOHdGh0ggKspBkZhCGkHAsAwIgKCoLobh4OwZAUBAaAaVpZTIMAACcrhUFpxaUHY5FoXYlgpH8yEkaQ%2Bm6OqADytCsE58mkFgNKiOwtn%2BXgYF5AymBSX5wq5OaPSifCcghaweB2MQjmaFgzmkU8ug5a0ND0EwbAcDw/CCMIoggBIYhSKldhSbAtDMO5KAnDJkVON0JncQhrSoG4CSQshAC0ADqbCthNwoEBlYwTYC6AiIoyALeNtCoKNELaLI6CjQyKR4MwdjsOtm2jW4KTqggUVRZJci5MNKhqNUmQmGoDSlNEQReMNb2CB4f0%2BF9kRlJwMiPXkiSVGkWgZIIOTQ7QBSpKDTQQzMhQA5jsPo%2BDrTSARXRcIhyGoehIXifizGGKNhjcBKyBrSZ8zOPSuCECQuoDBDYyaAZ2k85wobqKRtmUTRpwCd0QmkPl0sidhyGSdJskS4pKkQEg7QEGaBDkJQ%2BmadpggNlzP1FYwLDBeVADuGVuAVMsU0rYnIVsnBjHbhAIGMNN0wzTMs2z4vyZRt3MFgTgQK0NHcTJSGy2hCsyW74mqzJckUXHXAcvMJkmccerHIXnB0cxzHHLwScDMJVMq%2Br4ea/ASmqcbhk6Ub6km0ZIwiMACcyRZrBWRANl%2BfZLXEL5LluZ53m%2BaJAUD8Ffn4OFiiRdFomxcg8UhUlSeiQ1GUz1lPQuXNeD5d0JGFXQ1ulVwvACK4VXiJIQhpU1UAtW1RxpZdWQr1HOYkho%2BGihNKa50to7T2gdI6J0zoTQuldMC9BbqyGkA9eIPgXoaHhjUD65hLAlDBj9IGIRfBEPelQ4a%2BMfpI2GqjOG/h3rMPyHjMhjRwZ1CqLQxG3DwjfVJm0DoJMRYu3rn5amtN6aM37oKbiDEGIc3wEQTUntowC17lowY%2Bp%2BZhzATRAYAx5hmMsVY6xMs5ap0prIxuUks4azbtrEAut9aGz0j3TuIBXDm00YIK2JVba8AdswJ2d8FJJ1dg3PoBjva%2B39vIoOSjgBjBUWcUS2d%2BqkEjtHSgZNk7yxAIreJmcm4mJfvMQw1c6LF04hxcqtcZGiQzlUhSbikB73NCQbxKRgDSAVCIOQDAECoDthhOevjhDDRGVYVg4zJluw7qbYy3FXBrMcB5c0yypkhT3usYgQzG57ySPgAwt1WCsFQKQEJNsyqv0qgPGqX8Gq/wgP/DggDOplB6n1Sig1hrRUksTMqFRLkLLGRMg5zdYltOVt0AOCjg6ZLOOzbA%2BI4qaPURbYWotjF5NMc4CxPFDCcG4hyAYzEOQcmcPxJOct05OLVrkyiSdnCIvdhJTplEupeGUNwIAA)

Comment: Suppose that I want to store the value of countl into a variable in main. How would I do that? I am completely new to programming, so don't mind me asking.

Comment: @hash_includes_what With regard to my example `unsigned int countl = count_letters(text));  printf("%u Letter(s)  \n", countl);` - You store the return value of `count_letters` into the variable `countl` first. This value of `countl` do you print then in the call to `printf()`.

Comment: I am getting this error. "error: use of undeclared identifier 'text' "

Comment: @hash_includes_what Hmmm, When I compile it I got no errors. Your code needs to be different anywhere than the one in my answer. You can see that it should work [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ndconb).

Comment: I am declaring my function as:  `int count_letters(string text);`
and I am assigning the value in main as :`  int countl = count_letters(text); `
I copied and ran your code and it worked, I want to understand why my version of code doesn't work.

Comment: @hash_includes_what Oh, I think I spotted it. `unsigned int countl = count_letters(text));` needs to be `unsigned int countl = count_letters(text);` - One trailing  `)` too much from copy and past from the `printf()` call. Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: @hash_includes_what Here is now the version with the variable `countl` in `main` https://godbolt.org/z/4nK3nY

Comment: @hash_includes_what Also if you use `count_letters` with a return type of `unsigned int` you should declare `countl` of the same matching type.

Comment: @hash_includes_what If you still got problems I need to see the full code.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int count_letters(string text);
int main(void)

{
    int countl = count_letters(text);
        
 string text= get_string("Please enter text: ");
 

     printf("%i Letter(s)  \n",countl);
}
int count_letters(string text)
{
int countl= 0;
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
 {
if (isalpha(text[i]) != 0)
 {
countl++;
}
}
return countl;
}` 
This is the code, I am not sure as to why it is still giving error. "use of undeclared identifier 'text'"

Comment: @hash_includes_what You need to place `int countl = count_letters(text);` after `string text = get_string("Please enter text: ");` not before. Else `text` is not declared at this point of time.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for being such a great community member and helping me at every step.

Comment: @hash_includes_what I'm glad that I could help.

Comment: I need your help with another code. <https://codeshare.io/anyv11> please let me know why I am getting an error `use of undeclared identifier 'key'` while returning a value.

Answer (score 1):

looking at [`cs50.h`](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/src/cs50.h) header to see how `string` is defined:

```
typedef char *string;
```

so

```
int count_letters(string text[]);
```

defines an array of pointers of `char`.

When indexing `text[i]` the compiler returns a `string` when functions like `isalpha` expect a `char`. There's one dimension too much in the input.

You need a mere pointer on chars (constant is better too). Without `cs50` includes, since `count_letters` is not modifying the `text` data, I would write:

```
int count_letters(const char *text);
```

so if you really want to use `cs50` types, go for:

```
int count_letters(const string text);
```

Comment: This answer would be greater if you explain what the current `string[]` means, and how that is different from a `string`. Also, what is happening currently, when accessing `isalpha(text[i])` and `strlen(text)`

Comment: `const string text` just qualifies the pointer `text` with `const`; it does not declare a pointer to `const char`.

Comment: "`string text[]` defines an array of pointers of `char`" - AFAIK this isn't true. The array notation is equivalent to a pointer in this case too so you end up with that `string text[]` is equal to `char** text`.

Answer (score 1):

As `string` is an alias for the type `char *` then this function declaration

```
int count_letters(string text[]);
```

is equivalent to the declaration

```
int count_letters( char * text[] );
```

that is in turn equivalent to

```
int count_letters( char ** text );
```

So within the function for example these expressions

```
strlen(text)
```

and

```
isalpha(text[i])
```

are incorrect because in the first expression the used argument has the type `char **` instead of the type `char *` and in the second expression the argument has the type `char *` instead of `char`.

Moreover the call of `strlen` is redundant.

The function should be declared and defined the following way

```
size_t count_letters( string text );
```

and

```
size_t count_letters( string text )
{
    size_t countl = 0;

    for ( ; *text; ++text )
    {
        if ( isalpha(( unsigned char )*text ) ) ++countl;
    }

    return countl;
}
```

Pay attention to that it would be more correctly to declare the function the following way

```
size_t count_letters( const char *text );
```

because the passed string is not changed in the function. To write `const string text` does not make sense and is not the same as `const char *`

And you forgot to call the function in main. You have to write

```
printf("%zu Letter(s)  \n", count_letters(text ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of the parameter needs to match the type of the expression you’re passing - in this case, you’d be passing an expression of type `string`, so the prototype needs to be

```
int count_letters(string text)
```

To get that count, you have to *call* the function from `main`.  You can either do that from within `printf` call:

```
printf("%i Letter(s)  \n", count_letters(text));
```

or you can create another variable to store that result:

```
string text = get_string( ... );
int len = count_letters( text );
printf( "%i Letter(s)  \n", len );
```

The variable `countl` is local to the `count_letters` function and is not accessible from `main`.

**<Gratuitous Rant>**

The CS50 `string` typedef name is a *lie* because what it aliases *is not a string*, and after seeing enough questions from people taking the CS50 course I believe it is actually a hinderance to learning C; it *completely* misrepresents how strings are represented and handled, and if you do any C programming outside of this course you will be completely unprepared for how string processing (and I/O in general) actually work.

Get comfortable, this is gonna take a while.

In C, a *string* is a sequence of characters including a zero-valued *terminator*.  The string `"hello"` is represented as the sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`.

Strings (including string literals like `"hello"`) are *stored* in arrays of character type:

```
char text[] = "hello"; // array size is determined by the length of the initializer
```

or

```
char text[SOME_SIZE]; // where SOME_SIZE is large enough to store what we need
strcpy( text, "hello" );
```

Since strings are stored in arrays, you cannot use the `=` operator to assign them (outside of an initializer as shown above, but that’s only valid for a *declaration*).  You either need to use a library function like `strcpy` (for arrays that contain strings) or `memcpy` (for arrays that contain anything else), or you need to assign each element individually:

```
text[0] = 'h';
text[1] = 'e';
...
text[5] = 0;
```

Now, under most circumstances, an *expression* of type "array of `T`" (including string literals like `”hello"`) will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element.  So, if we call a function like

```
count_letters( text );
```

it’s exactly the same as writing

```
count_letters( &text[0] );
```

and what `count_letters` actually receives is a *pointer* of type `char *`, and we’d declare the prototype as

```
int count_letters( char *str ) {...}
```

When you write something like

```
char *str = "hello";
```

you’re assigning the *address* of the first character of the string to `str`, not the string contents themselves.

`string` is a typedef name, or alias, for the type `char *` defined in `cs50.h`.  It is not a part of the C language or standard C library.  The problem is that `char *` ***is not a string***.  It *may* point to the first character of a string.  It may point to the first character of a sequence that is *not* a string.  It may point to a single character that’s not part of a larger sequence.  When we’re dealing with strings we often deal with expressions of type `char *`, but an expression of type `char *` is not, in and of itself, a string.

The `get_string` function (again, part of the `cs50` library and not a standard C library function) performs a lot of magic under the hood to *dynamically* allocate an array to store the string and returns a *pointer* to the first element (which is what you’re actually assigning).  It’s slick, it’s handy, but again, it *completely* misrepresents how C actually does things.

**</Gratuitous Rant>**